# How to sort a joined table with having the header just once in the output

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new with the codeigniter framework, and learning on how to use the MVC pattern. I'm trying to achieve an output but that isn't really working for me, allow me to illustrate my problem with the code:

I have 3 tables in my DB

```
CREATE TABLE carBrand
(
    pk_brandID int,
    brand varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE carModel
(
    pk_modelID int,
    model varchar(255)
)

CREATE TABLE brandModel
(
    pk_brandmodelID int,
    project varchar(255),
    carOWner varchar(255),
    buildyear varchar(255),
    fk_brandID int,
    fk_modelID int
)
```

At the moment I'm joing the tables with a join like this in my model

```
function getCarbyOwner(){
    $this->db->join('carBrand', 'carBrand.pk_brandID = brandModel.fk_brandID');
    $this->db->join('carModel', 'carModel.pk_modelID = brandModel.fk_modelID');
    $this->db->where('carOwner', $$this->session->userdata('logged_in_owner'));
    $q = $this->db->get('brandModel');
    return $q->result();
}
```

That outputs this in my view - depending on which record is first in the db

**brand 1**

> *model
>
> **brand 1**
>   *model
>
> **brand 3**
>   *model
>
> **brand 2**
>   *model
>
> **brand 3**
>   *model

But I am having difficulties with outputting the data
What I basically want is the following output

> **Brand 1**
>   *model
>   *model
>   *model
>
> **Brand 2**
>   *model
>   *model
>   *model
>
> **Brand 3**
>   *model
>   *model
>   *model

This is my controller

```
function index(){
    if($car= $this->car_model->getCarbyOwner()){
        $data['car'] = $car;
        $this->load->view('carview', $car);
    }
}
```

The view:

```
if(isset($car)){
    foreach($car as $r){
        $r->brand;
        $r->model
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the result I want to have?

### EDIT

I've implemented a few suggestions, but now it isn't outputting everything.

**The records I have in the table brandModel are for example like this:**

```
pk_brandmodelID | project | carowner | buildyear | fk_brandID | fk_modelID
1               | proj A  | frank    | 2012      | 1          | 6 
2               | proj B  | Jef      | 2002      | 2          | 1
3               | proj C  | jeffrey  | 2013      | 1          | 5
4               | proj X  | frank    | 2010      | 2          | 2
5               | proj Y  | george   | 2008      | 1          | 3
```

Let's say brand 1 = audi and brand 2 is Mercedes
**The wanted output is like this**

> **Audi**
>   model fk_id 6
>   model fk_id 5
>   model fk_id 3
>
> **Mercedes**
>   model fk_id 1
>
> model fk_id 2

**But now I'm only getting**

> **Audi**
>   model fk_id 6
>
> **Mercedes**
>   model fk_id 1

And I have used the following code:

**Model**

```
function getCarbyOwner(){
    $this->db->join('carBrand', 'carBrand.pk_brandID = brandModel.fk_brandID');
    $this->db->join('carModel', 'carModel.pk_modelID = brandModel.fk_modelID');
    $this->db->where('carOwner', 'xxx');
    $q = $this->db->get('brandModel');
    if($result = $q->result())
    {
        foreach($result as $key => $value)
        {
            $d[$value->pk_brandID]['brand'] = $value->brand;
            $d[$value->pk_brandID]['data'][$value->pk_modelID] = $value;
        }
        return $d;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

**View**

```
if(isset($x)){
    foreach($x as $r)
    {
        echo $r['brand']."<br />";
        foreach($r['data'] as $v)
        {
            echo $v->model."<br />";
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well .. here is the funny part: CodeIgniter has nothing to do with MVC. It uses the names, but has nothing in common with MVC design pattern.

Comment: @tereško what do you exactly mean?? The following comes from the site of codeigniter: "CodeIgniter is based on the Model-View-Controller development pattern. MVC is a software approach that separates application logic from presentation. In practice, it permits your web pages to contain minimal scripting since the presentation is separate from the PHP scripting." source: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: Since I have been over this several times already, the explanation will be brief. The separation described above does not manifest in CI. "Application logic" is usually used to describe interaction between storage abstraction and domain entities. It's only one of the aspects for the model layer (yes, it is a layer, not a class or object). On the other hand, presentation logic get separated in the parts that deal with input and output. Input is purview of controllers, bur ALL of the logic regarding output is for views. And views are instances, not dumb templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make new method into CAR modal

```
function getCarModels(){
    $modalData = array();
    $this->db->join('carBrand', 'carBrand.pk_brandID = brandModel.fk_brandID');
    $this->db->where('carOwner', $$this->session->userdata('logged_in_owner'));
     $q = $this->db->get('brandModel');

    if($result = $query->result())
    {
        foreach($result as $key => $value)
        {
            $modalData[$value-pk_brandID[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $brandData;
}
```

and into controller file

```
$data['car']  = $this-car_modelgetCarModels();
```

and into view file

```
 foreach($car as $r)
        {
            echo $r[0]->brand."<br />";
            foreach($r as $v)
            {
                echo $v->model."<br />";
            }
            echo "<br />";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easiest to get the resultset ordered, add something like this after the last `->where`

```
$this->db->order_by("brandModel", "asc");
```

I'm not an expert on CodeIgniter, but the goal here is to get this appended to the SQL statement:

```
ORDER BY brand_name_col ASC, model_name_col ASC
```

Then it's just a matter of suppressing the display of "brand" when the value matches the preceding value.

Answer (score 0):

I would only use 2 tables instead of 3 like this:

```
CREATE TABLE carBrand
(
    pk_brandID int,
    brand varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE carModel
(
    pk_modelID int,
    fk_brandID int,
    model varchar(255),
    project varchar(255),
    carOWner varchar(255),
    buildyear varchar(255)
);
```

The query:

```
function getCarbyOwner($owner){
    $q = $this->db->select('b.brand, m.model')
                  ->from('carBrand b')
                  ->join('carModel m', 'b.pk_brandID = m.fh_brandID')
                  ->where('m.carOwner', $owner);
                  ->group_by('b.brand')
                  ->order_by('b.brand', 'ASC')
                  ->get();
                  ->result();
    return $q;
}
```

Controller:

```
$owner = $this->session->userdata('logged_in_owner');
$data[cars] = $this->car_model->getCatbyOwner($owner);
$this->load->view('car_view', $data);
```

**EDIT:** 3 tables query:

```
function getCarbyOwner($owner){
        $q = $this->db->select('b.brand, m.model, bm.carOwner')
                      ->from('branModel bm')
                      ->join('carModel m', 'm.pk_modelID = bm.fk_modelID')
                      ->join('carBrand b', 'b.pk_brandID = bm.fk_brandID')
                      ->where('bm.carOwner', $owner);
                      ->group_by('b.brand')
                      ->order_by('b.brand', 'ASC')
                      ->get();
                      ->result();
        return $q;
    }
```

Try the above if it works for you but just to let you know, JOINS are pretty expensive, at least more expensive then my first suggestion.

Comment: I need the 3 tables, because at the moment, I made the tables and the structure less complex to explain myself here :)

Answer (score 0):

You could either do it the way Spencer said - which is probably the easiest, least overhead way of doing it...

Or you could also group your result set into an Array of Arrays.  Meaning you'll have to iterate through your resultset in the controller and put the corresponding values into the correct buckets.

e.g.

```
 array Cars
     ( 'Brand1', array(..),
       'Brand2', array(..),
     ...
     )
```

and then iterate through nested loops in your UI.

Comment: I'll take a shot at this approach, I'll let you know how it went

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating through an array of cars, echoing out each brand, and then each model. Even if you were to append an "order by" clause to your sql, it wouldn't change that.

You need to separate the cars out by brand, like dispake said.

```
foreach($car as $r)
        {
        if($r->brand = "Brand 1")
        {
            $brand1[] = $r->model;
        }
        else if($r->brand = "Brand 2")
        etc etc....
```

That will leave you with 3 arrays, one for each brand, that you can then output as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly i agree with what **Matteo T.** says. Your tables seems to require another look into as i don't think the relationships between tables like that is efficient. Regardless, this is my answer.

your current model function isn't wrong actually, its just not sorted properly.

**Model**

```
function getCarbyOwner(){
    $this->db->join('carBrand', 'carBrand.pk_brandID = brandModel.fk_brandID');
    $this->db->join('carModel', 'carModel.pk_modelID = brandModel.fk_modelID');
    $this->db->where('carOwner', 'frank'); // make sure the car owner is exists
    $q = $this->db->get('brandModel');
    if($result = $q->result())
    {
        foreach($result as $key => $value)
        {
            $d[$value->pk_brandID]['brand'] = $value->brand;
            $d[$value->pk_brandID]['data'][$value->pk_modelID] = $value;
        }
        // test print_r($d); here to check the result
        return $d;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

**View**

```
if(isset($x)){
    foreach($x as $r)
    {
            // test print_r($r); here to check the result
        echo $r['brand']."<br />";
        foreach($r['data'] as $v)
        {
                // test print_r($v); here to check the result
            echo $v->model."<br />";
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

basically the idea is to change the standard result set into more suited array list, as suggested by **dispake**.

take note that my answer is just a sample. and probably does not suit your request completely.

**ADDED-EDITS**

the main idea of the sorting that i suggested is to sort the result set from (roughly something like this)

```
array( 
[0] => array ( 
    brandModelID => 1,
    project => 'proj A',
    carowner => 'frank',
    buildyear => 2012,
    brandID => 1,
    modelID => 6,
),
[1] => array (
    brandModelID => 2, 
    project => 'proj B', 
    carowner => 'frank', 
    buildyear => 2002, 
    brandID => 2, 
    modelID => 1, 
),
[2] => array (
    brandModelID => 3, 
    project => 'proj C', 
    carowner => 'frank', 
    buildyear => 2013, 
    brandID => 1, 
    modelID => 5, 
),
[3] => array (
    brandModelID => 4, 
    project => 'proj X', 
    carowner => 'frank', 
    buildyear => 2010, 
    brandID => 2, 
    modelID => 2, 
),
[4] => array (
    brandModelID => 5, 
    project => 'proj Y', 
    carowner => 'frank', 
    buildyear => 2008, 
    brandID => 1, 
    modelID => 3, 
)
```

to

```
array( 
[1] =>  array( // key is brandID
    ['brand'] => 'something',
    ['data'] array(
        [6] =>  array ( // key is modelID
            brandModelID => 1,
            project => 'proj A',
            carowner => 'frank',
            buildyear => 2012,
            brandID => 1,
            modelID => 6,
    ),
        [2] => array ( // key is modelID
            brandModelID => 3, 
            project => 'proj C', 
            carowner => 'frank', 
            buildyear => 2013, 
            brandID => 1, 
            modelID => 5, 
        ),
        [4] => array ( // key is modelID
            brandModelID => 5, 
            project => 'proj Y', 
            carowner => 'frank', 
            buildyear => 2008, 
            brandID => 1, 
            modelID => 3, 
        )
    )
),
[2] => array( // key is brandID
    ['brand'] => 'something',
    ['data'] array(
        [1] => array ( // key is modelID
            brandModelID => 2, 
            project => 'proj B', 
            carowner => 'frank', 
            buildyear => 2002, 
            brandID => 2, 
            modelID => 1, 
        ),
        [3] => array ( // key is modelID
            brandModelID => 4, 
            project => 'proj X', 
            carowner => 'frank', 
            buildyear => 2010, 
            brandID => 2, 
            modelID => 2, 
        )
    )
)
```

no matter how i look, the function looks fine like this. There isn't any problem with the code. You only need to customize on what to show and what not to show. try using print_r() to check the results. I marked where you might need to check.

Comment: I will also take a look at this one and try it, firstly looking at your code I have to rethink it a bit more, because not everything is clear for me at the moment. I'll revise your code a bit and try to implement it. What Matteo T and you are saying about the table, isn't complety true, because for this example I just made the tables a bit less complex than it actually is. There are more fields involved but for my example to explain and getting me on the right track this was perfect :)

Comment: Got me confused there, I got it to work for 50%.
Now Im getting 
Brand 1
 - model

Brand 2
 -Model

But always just 1 model while a brand has more than 1 model

Comment: Actually, i don't really get your table relationships.
it sure does seems to be [brandModel] 1:M [carBrand], [brandModel] 1:M  [carModel]

Comment: Can you maybe do teamviewer for a moment, maybe it'll be more easier like that to show you?

Comment: nah, maybe you could edit your question and add the updated functions.

Comment: Ok :) give me a moment please

Comment: I just have edited my question, if you would please take a look at it

Comment: basically the same as my suggestion. err, well i really do mean its just a sample. usually, i would use the print_r() function on the parts that are curious to me. first would be the resulting data of the model function. Does it generate the correct value? (refer edited answer). 
good luck.